# AWS service like ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

is there an **AWS service that can maintain an OS like ansible** ?

I mean: install package1 and package2, create folder /foo/bar, tune sysctl, ...

I don't mean: manage AWS ressource like route53, S3 buckets, loadbalancer, ...

Comment: What's wrong with just using *Ansible* for this?

Comment: nothing wrong. but if AWS has a managed service, often better integrated with their stack. i'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like [AWS Opsworks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/)? It's hosted Chef / Puppet. You could also consider [Systems Manager State Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-state.html), not sure if it will do everything you need but it looks easy enough.

You can use Ansible if you like, but there's not a service to manage that for you.